# trim() not working for strings input from console

Tags: java

I can't understand why trim() is not working in this case. Please verify the below code-

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string:");
    String s=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("length is:"+s.length());        
    System.out.println("trimmed length is:"+
        s.trim().length());
```

Now if I enter a string in the console using spaces in between, then both the length and trimmed length are showing the same value. Please note that its working fine for string entered in the program itself ie. `String s="   Man  "` is working fine but why not the above.

Comment: trim does not remove in between spaces.. try replacing the space by ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) removes only the leading and trailing spaces, not the ones in between the characters:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Always read the docs of a function before using it to check does it really do what you intend to do. If not then are there any workarounds? If yes then which would be most optimized and this is where you can post on SO(Just a suggestion of-course).

In your case [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) are the docs of trim() function of String. As it clearly says `Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted` you cannot make it's use to remove spaces in between words. You may want to try

```
s.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
```

You can view the docs for same [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine, make sure you are entering input without "", like
-----Man---- not like "----Man----" where - is space, as trim() trims leading and trailing spaces not the ones which come in between the characters.